# Separating classes using IDs

Tags: jquery

I have two picture on which a DIV shows upon hovering, showing some user info. The looks of it is as intended, but I can't figure how to only show the info on the hovered image.

How can I do this?

Here's a live working example of the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/uvHw4/

Raw javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.start_profile_container_text').hide();
    $('.start_profile_container').mouseenter(function() {
        $('.start_profile_container_text').show('slide', { direction: "down"} ,'fast');
    });

    $('.start_profile_container').mouseout(function() {
        $('.start_profile_container_text').hide('slide', { direction: "down"} ,'fast');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.start_profile_container_text').hide();

  $('.start_profile_container').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.start_profile_container_text', this).show('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  });

  $('.start_profile_container').mouseout(function () {
    $('.start_profile_container_text', this).hide('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  });

});
```

The difference to your code is simply adding a this to the show/hide function to relate to the actual element.

Answer (score 1):

Pass current object in the context to address then element in descendants.

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/uvHw4/5/)**

```
 $('.start_profile_container').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.start_profile_container_text', this).show('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.start_profile_container_text').hide();

  $('.start_profile_container').mouseenter(function () {
    $('.start_profile_container_text', this).show('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  });

  $('.start_profile_container').mouseleave(function () {
    $('.start_profile_container_text', this).hide('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  });

});
```

Use context to find `.start_profile_container_text` only inside hovered div: `$('.start_profile_container_text', this)` where this is an element which points to a current div.

Also, see I've replaced `mouseout` with `mouseleave` which should work better than `mouseout` (text will not jump up and down. Difference is that `mouseout` will happen even if mouse goes to a child element, and `mouseleave` does not happen if you move from an element to its child)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uvHw4/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try using children() DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/gDZey/

```
$(this).children('.start_profile_container_text').show('slide', {
  direction: "down"
}, 'fast');
```

I would propose to use http://api.jquery.com/hover/ for this case.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.start_profile_container_text').hide();

  $('.start_profile_container').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.start_profile_container_text').show('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  },

  function () {
    $(this).find('.start_profile_container_text').hide('slide', {
      direction: "down"
    }, 'fast');
  });

});
```

This code work fine. And I suggest using `hover` instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseout`.

And here is the demo http://jsfiddle.net/uvHw4/3/

Answer (score 0):

u can use [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) instead of two functions..

```
$('.start_profile_container').hover(
   function () {
      $('.' + this.className +'_text', this).show('slide', { direction: "down"}, 'fast');
   },
   function () {
      $('.' + this.className +'_text', this).hide('slide', {direction: "down"}, 'fast');
   }
);
```